# Updating a Label From a Nested View Model's Property

Tags: wpf, mvvm, properties, viewmodel

Before I get to my question/problem, here is the basic structure of my application:

In my MainWindow.xaml (the main view in this case) I have a Label (I realize I should change this to a TextBlock, but that is a separate issue):

```
<Label Name="StatusLabel" Content="{Binding Path=Status}"/>
```

It's corresponding ViewModel (MainWindowViewModel) contains another ViewModel (SiteListViewModel) and a Status property:

```cs
public class MainWindowViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public SiteListViewModel SiteList { get; set; }
    public String Status
    {
        get { return SiteList.Status; }
    }
}
```

As you can see, MainWindowViewModel's Status property returns the SiteListViewModel instances' Status property, which is defined as such:

```cs
public class SiteListViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private string status;
    public String Status 
    {
        get { return this.status; }
        set
        {
            this.status = value;
            base.OnPropertyChanged("Status");
        }
    }
}
```

SiteListViewModel's Status property is updated in various places during asynchronous processes to keep the user informed as to what is going on. This is done with simple assignment calls such as:

```cs
Status = String.Format(Properties.Resources.SiteListViewModel_Status_LoadingJobs, count + 1, totalSites);
```

Another important note, Both MainWindowViewModel and SiteListViewModel inherit from ViewModelBase which implements INotifyPropertyChanged.

*Now for the actual question/problem:*

**The label does not update.**

However, if I change the binding in the view to this:

```
<Label Name="StatusLabel" Content="{Binding Path=SiteList.Status}"/>
```

It works fine. Which seems to indicate that I am missing something at the MainWindowViewModel level. I could leave it as it is, but that reaches into the structure of the child view model, which is not something I want to do.

Can someone point to what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course it does not update, the binding system listens to change events for the property you bind to on the type owning that property, you do not fire any notifications at all.

You could forward the notifications of the nested VM:

```cs
public MainWindowViewModel
{
    SiteList.PropertyChanged += (s,e)
        => if (e.PropertyName == "Status") OnPropertyChanged("Status");
}
```

Where `OnPropertyChanged` is a method to raise `PropertyChanged`; your VM base-class should have something like that.

I would recommend dropping the property though, it's redundant as you can bind directly though `SiteList` (also that property should fire change notifications in its setter). Also you would need to detach the handler from the old instance and re-attach it to the new instance whenever the `SiteList` changes (could be done in the setter as well).

Comment: I know it will work if I bind directly to `SiteList.Status` (I said it near the end of the post), but it feels like I am breaking encapsulation by doing that. I guess I had a poor understanding of how the PropertyChanged events' are handled. I thought it didn't matter what "level" the event was fired as long as it was bound to "parent" property at the XAML/UI level.

Comment: +1 to get this off my "Unanswered Questions" list. and because you answered pretty much the same thing I did at the same time :)

Comment: @H.B regarding 'binding system listens to change events for the property you bind to on the type owning that property' can you provide a link to a documentations that states that ? Thanks

Comment: @IronHide It is kind of complicated, i would recommend reading the [binding sources overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/binding-sources-overview) (and the [general data binding overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data) for more information. The point of that statement in this answer was that the binding system will not be magically informed about change notifications when a property just points to another object's property which would have notifications.

Comment: @H.B I think that the following statement "If your binding source implements one of these notification mechanisms, target updates happen automatically" from the first lik is what you were referring to is that correct ? The reason why im asking all this is that I always wonder how one would figure something out if there was not SO answer for it. Although even if I had read that sentence before I am not sure if I would make that connection anyway, it should be explained more directly in that article just like you did.

Comment: @IronHide That is what i was referring to, yes. WPF is complex, it is not something you can or are supposed to be able to use without reading documentation. You can learn most things from these articles on MSDN, they usually explain all mechanisms in high enough detail.

Answer (score 0):

Just because something implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` does not mean it will automatically know when properties change. You need to raise the PropertyChanged event in your code.

In your example, that would be done by registering to `SiteListViewMode.PropertyChanged`, and raising a `PropertyChanged` notification for `Status` whenever the status changes.

```cs
public class MainWindowViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public SiteListViewModel SiteList { get; set; }
    public String Status
    {
        get { return SiteList.Status; }
    }

    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        // Of course, verify property isn't null first. 
        // Also, it's probably best to attach this in the setter
        // so you can unhook the event from old items too
        SiteList.PropertyChanged += SiteList_PropertyChanged;
    }

    void SiteList_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.PropertyName == "Status")
            RaisePropertyChanged("Status");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `MainWindow`'s `DataContext` is `MainWindowViewModel`.

`Label` will then "inherit" the same `DataContext`, so `Label`'s `DataContex`t is also `MainWindowViewModel`.  This is why you must do `SiteList.Status`. (Because you're not raising `PropertyChanged` in `MainWindowViewModel` but are in `SiteListViewModel`.)

Comment: That is not the point here, `Status` exists on the MainWindowViewModel as well.

Comment: right-o. minor update to explain why one syntax works but not the other.